# how to use Arabic in word2vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, arabic, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

i am trying to make a book recommendation sys using word2vec like in this link
https://medium.com/@ashok.1055/building-book-recommendation-system-16f2cdf615f2

and when i use Arabic title in the recommendation function it gives me an error

`recommendations("الخليفة")`

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._unpack_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'الخليفة'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-d299fc330241> in <module>
----> 1 recommendations2("الخليفة")

<ipython-input-56-c761695971d2> in recommendations2(title)
     16     indices = pd.Series(df1.index, index = df1['Title']).drop_duplicates()
     17 
---> 18     idx = indices[title]
     19     sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similaritiess[idx]))
     20     sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'الخليفة'
```

I am using these methods to preprocess data

```
# Clean/Normalize Arabic Text

import string
arabic_punctuations = '''`÷×؛<>_()*&^%][ـ،/:"؟.,'{}~¦+|!”…“–ـ'''
english_punctuations = string.punctuation
punctuations_list = arabic_punctuations + english_punctuations

# same as #remove tashkeel in clear_str()
arabic_diacritics = re.compile("""
                             ّ    | # Tashdid
                             َ    | # Fatha
                             ً    | # Tanwin Fath
                             ُ    | # Damma
                             ٌ    | # Tanwin Damm
                             ِ    | # Kasra
                             ٍ    | # Tanwin Kasr
                             ْ    | # Sukun
                             ـ     # Tatwil/Kashida
                         """, re.VERBOSE)

def remove_diacritics(text):
    text = re.sub(arabic_diacritics, '', text)
    return text
# --------------------------

def remove_punctuations(text):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', punctuations_list)
    return text.translate(translator)

# -----------------------------

def normalize_arabic(text):
    text = re.sub("[إأآا]", "ا", text)
    text = re.sub("ى", "ي", text)
    text = re.sub("ؤ", "ء", text)
    text = re.sub("ئ", "ء", text)
    text = re.sub("ة", "ه", text)
    text = re.sub("گ", "ك", text)
    return text
```

and the two functions

```
# Generate the average word2vec for each book description

def vectors2(x):
    
    # Creating a list for storing the vectors (description into vectors)
    global word_embeddingss
    word_embeddingss = []
    

    # Reading the each book description 
    for line in df1['c']:
        avgword2vecc = None
        countt = 0
        for word in line.split():
            if word in google_model.wv.vocab:
                countt += 1
                if avgword2vecc is None:
                    avgword2vecc = google_model.wv[word]
                else:
                    avgword2vecc = avgword2vecc + google_model.wv[word]
                
        if avgword2vecc is not None:
            avgword2vecc = avgword2vecc / countt
        
            word_embeddingss.append(avgword2vecc)
```

```
# Recommending the Top 5 similar books

def recommendations2(title):
    
    # Calling the function vectors
    
    vectors2(df1)
    
    # finding cosine similarity for the vectors

    cosine_similaritiess = cosine_similarity(word_embeddingss, word_embeddingss)

    # taking the title and book image link and store in new data frame called books
    books = df1[['Title', 'Cover']]
    #Reverse mapping of the index
    indices = pd.Series(df1.index, index = df1['Title']).drop_duplicates()
         
    idx = indices[title]
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similaritiess[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:6]
    book_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    recommend = books.iloc[book_indices]
    for index, row in recommend.iterrows():

        response = requests.get(row['Cover'])
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.title(row['Title'])
```

the data set for Arabic books I download it from here
https://www.kaggle.com/code/jjresnick/jamalon-arabic-books-dataset/data
and I use it from google drive in the code

```
df1 =pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/jamalon-big.csv')
```

it works for English recommendations but didn't work for Arabic .. so if you can help me with this error?
or i must use other methods / model for Arabic recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the same method as in that article you've chosen as inspiration should work for Arabic book titles/descriptions, if you have a good set of Arabic word-vectors.

But, right off the bat, with regard to the specific error you're getting, you should note:

- Sets of word-vectors only know vectors for individual words. Though I don't know Arabic & it's word-delimiting standards well, the `KeyError` you've shown seems to be for a multi-word text, with spaces inside it. No plain Arabic word-vector set will be able to return a lookup vector for a multiword string.
- But, it seems your `KeyError` might actually be from a key-based lookup on a Pandas datastructure. But, it's not clear from the 'Traceback' which of *your* lines of code initiated the set-of-calls that led to the error. Did you leave out some of the error message, or has your local interpreter/notebook been reconfigured to show fewer traceback frames? An error is always easier to understand with *all* frames of traceback, so if you can edit your question (or ask future questions) with *all* traceback, please do so.
- Even when looking up individual words from a set of word-vectors, you have to be ready for the possibility some words won't be found in your model. In some cases, it can make sense to just silently ignore words not present – the rest of the words will still give a good result. In other cases, you'll want to show some message that a word was ignored, but still return the best-possible result with the remaining words. But in others, a failure to look up a word (if it's the only one), or all words, might need to show an error. It depends.

However, there are some other general problems with your approach you should correct for a more robust, understandable, and debuggable approach.

- Don't use a `global` in the way you have, declared within a function, then used in another - it makes what affects what other calculations far harder to analyze. If you genuinely need some global/top-level datastructure – such as your collection of *all* books – declare it at the top level. And usually, you'll want to avoid writing functions that reference the global directly, instead *passing it in* where it's needed.
- For describing what you've done, your codes behavior will be highly dependent on the type/contents of the `df1` variable - which you don't describe in any way. A good question would give some hint, via its setup code, or some demonstration output, of what the `df1` variable has in it.
- `x` isn't a good parameter-name; it should be more-descriptively named. And if `vectors2()` is meant to be a one-time initialization of the (global) vectors, from the other-global `df1`, it probably should *not* be called *every* time you ask for recommendations-based-on-title - but just once, before and outside the request-for-recommendations.

The approach you're trying **can** work, but you should clean up the code naming/organization, & if still getting a similar error, put improved details (& especially a more-detailed error traceback showing exactly which lines of **your** code trigger the error) into this question or a followup one to get more-specific help. Good luck!

Comment: I cannot understand some points of your answer but i edited the question if you can help with it

Comment: i use this to train .. "  google_model.train(corpus, total_examples=google_model.corpus_count, epochs = 5)" .. and It gives warnings

Comment: WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:Effective 'alpha' higher than previous training cycles
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 1 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (4302)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 2 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (4302)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 3 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (4302)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 4 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (4302)

(0, 0)

Comment: With the added 'traceback' info, it's clear that the initial `KeyError` you received was triggered by your line-of-code `idx = indices[title]`, inside the `recommendations2()` function. That means that error doesn't involve word2vec at all: just your loading into a Pandas datastructure, & lookup there. So to debug that, you need to just focus on steps leading up to there: do they all make sense? If you look at the interim state of the variables after each step, do they contain the right values for the next state?

Comment: This new set-of-warnings you're reporting in a comment is also the kind of multi-line info that's easier to read inside a formatted question text. But it also seems a different problem, & requires more context code to understand – where did the `google_model` come from? (It's declaration & initialization isn't shown anywhere.) But, just from your excerpt, a bunch of problems are already evident: (1) the reference to `base_any2vec` implies you're using a several-years-old outdated version of Gensim - you should try to use the latest release for fixes & to match the best online docs/examples. …

Comment: (2) The warning "Effective 'alpha' higher than previous training cycles" implies you're calling `train()` on a model that was already trained - which isn't a standard practice, & should really only be done by advanced users trying nonstandard experiments; (3) The warning "supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (4302)" means you told the `train()` method to expect 4302 texts, but actually fed it **zero**. That means the `corpus` object you passed-into `train()` didn't have anything useful in it.

Comment: With this many things amiss, you should really go back to the start & do everything in very-small steps, verifying every step as doing what you wanted before attempting the next step. In that process, if you hit specific blacks or errors, individual questions describing the whole minimal context to get to the problem will be more likely to generate good answers to help you.

Comment: it works now and thanks for the help .. the error was on the data set so I preprocessed the titles as well as the descriptions and it works

Comment: but I used another Arabic model by twitter